# Dynamically creating objects in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm fairly new to AS3, and I've been trying to make a side scrolling shooter.  I made some progress but I've hit a wall on the bullets themselves.  The code I've been using is:

```
var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();

function shoot() {
  circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF794B);
  circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 00, 7.5);
  circle.graphics.endFill();
  addChild(circle);
  circle.x = ship_mc.x;
  circle.y = ship_mc.y + 43; 
}
```

The problem with this is it only allows for one bullet on the screen at a time.  How can I change this so the bullets are created so that I can have an unlimited amount of them?

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer. And, when you have more reputation, upvote one or more answers.

Answer (score 2):

Create the object inside the method

```
function shoot() {
    var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
    circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF794B);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 00, 7.5);
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(circle);
    circle.x = ship_mc.x;
    circle.y = ship_mc.y + 43; 
}
```

Otherwise, you would only have one `circle` variable. This time, a new circle is created each time the method is called.

However, you will probably want to store all your circles somehow so that you can remove them later.

```
var allCircles: Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>();
function shoot() {
    var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
    circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF794B);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 00, 7.5);
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(circle);
    circle.x = ship_mc.x;
    circle.y = ship_mc.y + 43; 
    allCircles.push(circle);
}
```

Then, at a later time, you can loop through all your circles:

```
for each (var circle: Sprite in allCircles) {
    // do something with this circle
}
```

And to clear all circles:

```
for each (var circle: Sprite in allCircles) {
    removeChild(circle);
}
allCircles.clear();
```

Comment: But then he wouldn't have any way of interacting with the circles without accessing them through the `stage`'s children.

Comment: There was no mentioning about removing them in the original question :) But you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You want to store an array of `Sprite`s, not just one of them.  First you declare your `Array`:

```
var circles:Array = new Array();
```

Then you change your shoot function to make a new one and then push it into the `Array`:

```
function shoot() {
    var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();

    circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF794B);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 00, 7.5);
    circle.graphics.endFill();
    circle.x = ship_mc.x;
    circle.y = ship_mc.y + 43; 

    circles.push(circle);  
    addChild(circles[circles.length-1]);
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer Vector ahead of Array. Also, why not `addChild(circle);`? why complicate things by taking the last index of the array? But the idea of an array/vector is a good one.